# How can I see the raw SQL generated for an Ecto.Query?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have an `Ecto.Query` and a `Repo`, such that I can call `Repo.all(query)` and get results. However, the results are not what I expect.

How can I see the raw SQL the `Repo` will generate from the `Ecto.Query`?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can use [Ecto.Adapters.SQL.to_sql/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#to_sql/3):

```
iex> Ecto.Adapters.SQL.to_sql(:all, Repo, Post)
{"SELECT p.id, p.title, p.inserted_at, p.created_at FROM posts as p", []}
```

This function is also available under the repository with name `to_sql` if you’re using a SQL based adapter:

```
 iex> Repo.to_sql(:all, Post)
  {"SELECT p.id, p.title, p.inserted_at, p.created_at FROM posts as p", []}
```

The query can be any struct that implements the [Ecto.Queryable](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Queryable.html) protocol like `Post` above(which is a module that imports `Ecto.Schema`). An `Ecto.Query` can also be passed:

```
iex> query = Ecto.Query.where(Post, [p], p.views > 10)
iex> Ecto.Adapters.SQL.to_sql(:all, Repo, query)
{"SELECT p.id, p.title, p.inserted_at, p.created_at FROM posts as p WHERE p.views > $1", [10]}
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I needed to pass the `query` struct in place of `Post`.

Comment: @NathanLong You can pass anything that implements the Queryable protocol. That includes a query (obviously) but also anything that uses `Ecto.Schema`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021546/can-i-get-ecto-to-log-raw-sql

Comment: As of Ecto 3, the sql portion was split out into ecto_sql. Here is the updated link https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/3.0.3/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#to_sql/3 for future googlers.

Answer (score 18):

A convenient helper method for printing raw SQL

```
def print_sql(queryable) do
  IO.inspect(Ecto.Adapters.SQL.to_sql(:all, Repo, queryable))
  queryable
end

def list_new_foos() do
  Foo
  |> where([foo], foo.bar == 1337)
  |> limit(100)
  |> print_sql
  |> Repo.all()
end
```

Comment: This does not work for relations or preloads. You only get the parent level query in my case.

Comment: @DanAndreasson Can you please help me out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65183075/add-interval-to-timestamp-using-ecto-fragments/

Answer (score 4):

`to_sql/2` is added to the module you `use Ecto.Repo` on. By convention, that module would be named `MyApp.Repo` (MyApp would be your app's name). Internally, it would use `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.to_sql/3`, but `Ecto.Adapters.SQL` is more of an internal module.

Using it would look like:

```
iex> query = Ecto.Query.where(Post, [p], p.views > 10)
iex> MyApp.Repo.to_sql(:all, query)
{"SELECT p.id, p.title, p.inserted_at, p.created_at FROM posts as p WHERE p.views > $1", [10]}
```

Comment: On Elixir 1.7.3 I get `Repo.to_sql/3 is undefined or private`

Comment: @AlxVallejo It isn't `Repo.to_sql/3` but `MyApp.Repo.to_sql/2`. It should work with Ecto 3 or maybe even earlier

Answer (score 2):

It's basically `Gazler`s answer, but modified to use in code:

```
query = from p in Post
{query, params} = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.to_sql(:all, Repo, query)
IO.puts("#{query}, #{inspect(params)}")
```

You could use simple `IO.inspect`, but it'll output a query with backslashes.

Comment: I'm getting "Ecto.Queryable not implemented" errors for each of my relational models of the query. Do you have to preload them first? Seems odd that I would need to preload.