# How can I log `PREPARE` statements in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using a database tool (Elixir's Ecto) which uses [prepared statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-prepare.html#SQL-PREPARE-EXAMPLES) for most PostgreSQL queries. I want to see exactly how and when it does that.

I found the correct Postgres config file, `postgresql.conf`, by running `SHOW config_file;` in `psql`. I edited it to include

```
log_statement = 'all'
```

as Dogbert suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41021806/4376).

According to [the PostgreSQL 9.6 docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT), this setting should cause `PREPARE` statements to be logged.

After restarting PostgreSQL, I can `tail -f` its log file (the one specified by the `-r` flag when running the `postgres` executable) and I do see entries like this:

```
LOG:  execute ecto_728: SELECT i0."id", i0."store_id", i0."title", i0."description"
  FROM "items" AS i0 WHERE (i0."description" LIKE $1)
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '%foo%'
```

This corresponds to a query (albeit done over binary protocol, I think) like

```
EXECUTE ecto_728('%foo%');
```

However, **I don't see the original `PREPARE` that created `ecto_728`**.

I tried dropping and recreating the database. Afterwards, the same query is executed as `ecto_578`, so it seems that the original prepared statement was dropped with the database and a new one was created.

But when I search the PostgreSQL log for `ecto_578`, I only see it being executed, not created.

How can I see `PREPARE` statements in the PostgreSQL log?

Comment: Why, out of interest? You're seeing the query text at execution time anyway.

Comment: @CraigRinger No practical reason. :) I just want to understand the tools I'm using. Eg I'm curious if Ecto does the `PREPARE` when my code is compiled or when I boot my application. I suppose I can try compiling when PostgreSQL isn't running and see what happens.

Comment: Turns out that it does the `PREPARE` right before executing the query for the first time in a given session, because ["a named prepared-statement object lasts till the end of the current session"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-EXT-QUERY) so there's really no other way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, your queries are being prepared via the extended query protocol, which is distinct from a `PREPARE` statement. And according to the docs for `log_statement`:

> For clients using extended query protocol, logging occurs when an
>   Execute message is received

(Which is to say that logging does *not* occur when a Parse or Bind message is received.)

However, if you set [`log_min_duration_statement = 0`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-DURATION-STATEMENT), then:

> For clients using extended query protocol, durations of the Parse,
>   Bind, and Execute steps are logged independently

Enabling both of these settings together will give you two log entries per Execute (one from `log_statement` when the message is received, and another from `log_min_duration_statement` once execution is complete).

Comment: Nice! See my answer for what I found out, if you're curious. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41048490/4376) was correct; I'm just answering to add what I learned by trying it.

First, I was able to see three separate actions in the log: a `parse` to create the prepared statement, a `bind` to give the parameters for it, and an `execute` to have the database actually carry it out and return results. This is described [in the PostgreSQL docs for the "extended query protocol"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-EXT-QUERY).

```
LOG:  duration: 0.170 ms  parse ecto_918: SELECT i0."id", i0."store_id",
   i0."title", i0."description"
  FROM "items" AS i0 WHERE (i0."description" LIKE $1)
LOG:  duration: 0.094 ms  bind ecto_918: SELECT i0."id", i0."store_id",
  i0."title", i0."description"
  FROM "items" AS i0 WHERE (i0."description" LIKE $1)
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '%priceless%'
LOG:  execute ecto_918: SELECT i0."id", i0."store_id", 
  i0."title", i0."description"
  FROM "items" AS i0 WHERE (i0."description" LIKE $1)
DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '%priceless%'
```

This output was generated during a run of some automated tests. On subsequent runs, I saw the same query with a different name - eg, `ecto_1573`. This was without dropping the database or even restarting the PostgreSQL process. [The docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-EXT-QUERY) say that

> If successfully created, a named prepared-statement object lasts till
>   the end of the current session, unless explicitly destroyed.

So these statements have to be recreated on each session, and probably my test suite has a new session on each run.